# & character breaks received json by php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an array with more objects. If one object contains & character, every object after the & is not received by php. What might be the problem?

***THIS IS THE AJAX***

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "get.php");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send('data='+JSON.stringify(x));
```

***THIS IS THE PHP***

```
$json = $_POST['data'];
echo $json;
```

When entered

```
a&b
```

I got

```
[[{"x":x,"y":"x","z":"z"}],[{"w":a
```

Comment: try encoding  the JSON in the `get.php` and decoding in the receiver page

Comment: @Vijayaragavendran the problem is when i receive the JSON, i don't have what to encode if the JSON is already broke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use also the `encodeURIComponent` function:

```
xmlhttp.send('data=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `stringify` does not escape special characters like the `&`sign.
You should use `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(x))`